# How to plot multiple stacked x-axis boxplot using Plotly Python

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot

I wish to create multiple stacked x-axis using plotly python with below code. However, it only allows me to stack up 2 levels. Need Help. Thank you.

```
img1 = go.Figure()
img1.add_trace(go.Box(x=[df1['A'], df1['B'], df1['C']], y=df1['y_value']))
```

What I get:
[image: What i get]

What I want:
[image: What i wish to get]